# Android - C2DM simple server

Tags: c#, android, android-c2dm

I intent to create simple C# server for my Android C2DM client. Are there any usable snippets how to start?

Thanks

Comment: I have sample code for a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714230/c2dm-server-with-c/6879053#6879053

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [C2DM-Sharp](https://github.com/Redth/C2DM-Sharp)